# maven-dependency-plugin can't exclude test-scope dependencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm using [maven-dependency-plugin:copy-dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) to copy all dependencies into `target/dependency` directory. My `pom.xml` is:

```xml
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
```

version of plugin is latest: `3.1.2` (defined in parent pom).

This definition is working fine with one exception: it copies all test dependencies into `target` directory, where I need only runtime dependencies required for running target jar.

I tried to exclude it usgin `<excludeScope>` configuration like described in [the documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#excludeScope):

```xml
<configuration>
    <excludeScope>test</excludeScope>
</configuration>
```

But it makes the build failing with message:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:copy-dependencies (copy-dependencies) @ app ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  7.006 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-15T10:32:26+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:copy-dependencies (copy-dependencies) on project app:  Can't exclude Test scope, this will exclude everything. -> [Help 1]
```

I don't really understand why excluding the test scope will exclude everything, since without excluding `test` scope, the target directory contains all runtime dependencies too (along with test deps).

What could be the problem with excluding test dependencies? How to do it correctly?

*PS: Please don't suggest me using assembly or other fat-jar plugins here, since I'm copying dependency jars intentionally for Docker image build optimization: one layer for dependencies, another for jar, where dependencies layer is always cached until any dependency changed:*

```
COPY target/dependency  /usr/lib/app/lib
COPY target/${JAR_FILE} /usr/lib/app/target.jar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is probably in the `includeScope` description:

> Scope to include. An Empty string indicates all scopes (default). The scopes being interpreted are the scopes as Maven sees them, not as specified in the pom. In summary:
>
> - `runtime` scope gives runtime and compile dependencies,
> - `compile` scope gives compile, provided, and system dependencies,
> - `test` (default) scope gives all dependencies,
> - `provided` scope just gives provided dependencies,
> - `system` scope just gives system dependencies.

This means I would try with `<includeScope>runtime</includeScope>`.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude dependencies which are under test scope is to use includeScope runtime instead of the excludeScope as the plugin documentation for test means 'everything'